# ¿Cómo puedo sumar dos arrays en Bash?

Tags: array, bash

Tengo 2 arrays en un script bash y quiero sumarlos de forma que,
array1( 2 3 4 ) array2( 1 2 3 ) den como resultado array3 ( 3 5 7 )

Lo intente de esta manera.

```
declare -a arrayfinal
set arrayfinal=
for ((i=0; i<3; i++))
do
     arrayfinal[i] =array1[i]+array2[i]
done
echo "the result is"
echo "${arrayfinal[@]}"
```

array1 y array2 los tengo declarado fuera de esta función.

Al ejecutar el script me da error "orden no encontrada" en la linea donde tengo la suma de los 2 arrays, imagino que es error de sintaxis y he estado cambiando cosillas pero ninguna me funciona y en internet no he encontrado nada.

Answer (score 1):

Ya he sacado la solucion, la sintaxis era:

```
arrayfinal[i]=$((array1[i] + array2[i]))
```

Es decir:

```
for ((i=0; i<3; i++))
do
     arrayfinal[i]=$((array1[i] + array2[i]))
done
```